# Python Listing 2 Lists In Bullet Form

Tags: python, arrays, list

In my python code, I have 2 lists

```
myList = ["Example", "Example2", "Example3"]
mySecondList = ["0000", "1111", "2222"]
```

I need to print these so they look like this:

```
- Example 0000
- Example2 1111
- Example3 2222
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, many ways. Have you attempted it yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is, look for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
myList = ["Example", "Example2", "Example3"]
mySecondList = ["0000", "1111", "2222"]

for a, b in zip(myList, mySecondList):
    print("- {} {}".format(a, b))
```

> ```
> - Example 0000
> - Example2 1111
> - Example3 2222
> ```

The above will work if the lists have the same size, otherwise you should look into [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) or [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from `itertools` module depending on the python version you're using

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `zip()` or `zip_longest()` for your question.

But, without using any `built-in` modules/functions. You can create your own 'hacky' method by your own very similar to `zip()` function.

Here is an example:

```
def custom_zip(a, b, fill=None):
    length = max(len(a), len(b))
    for k in range(length):
        if k > len(a):
            yield fill, b[k]
        elif k > len(b):
            yield a[k], fill
        else:
            yield a[k], b[k]

a = ["Example", "Example2", "Example3"]
b = ["0000", "1111", "2222"]

for k, v in custom_zip(a,b):
    print("- {} {}".format(k, v))
```

Output:

```
- Example 0000
- Example2 1111
- Example3 2222
```

Also, you can take a look at the equivalent of `zip()` in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).